# I am creating billing form. In that i added textbox and dropdownlist in gridview. now in textbox1 i want to fetch price from database.

Tags: c#

I am creating billing form. In that i added textbox and dropdownlist in gridview. now in textbox1 i want to fetch price from database. so how do i get price in text box1? i tried a lot but i could not find the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <div>

        <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1"  runat="server"  ShowFooter="true"  
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
                                 OnRowCreated="Gridview1_RowCreated" 
           >  
        <Columns>  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Medicine Id" />  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Medicine Name">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
               <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>crocin</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>colgate</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
                 </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Price">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
                </ItemTemplate>  
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />  
                <FooterTemplate>  
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server"   
                                         Text="Add New Row"   
                                         onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />  
                </FooterTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField>  
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"   
                                            onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Remove</asp:LinkButton>  
                </ItemTemplate>  
            </asp:TemplateField>  
        </Columns>  
    </asp:gridview>  

    </div>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        Text="BtnSave" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>




in cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


namespace WebApplication11
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                SetInitialRow();
            }
        }




        // private ArrayList GetDummyData()
        //{

        // ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

        //arr.Add(new ListItem("Item1", "1"));
        //arr.Add(new ListItem("Item2", "2"));
        //arr.Add(new ListItem("Item3", "3"));
        //arr.Add(new ListItem("Item4", "4"));
        // arr.Add(new ListItem("Item5", "5"));

        //return arr;
        // }
        // private void FillDropDownList(DropDownList ddl)
        //{
        // ArrayList arr = GetDummyData();

        // foreach (ListItem item in arr)
        // {
        //  ddl.Items.Add(item);
        // }
        // }
        private void SetInitialRow()
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = null;

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));//for DropDownList selected item   
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));//for DropDownList selected item  
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   


            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
            // dr["Column3"] = 555;
            dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
            dr["Column4"] = string.Empty;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            //Store the DataTable in ViewState for future reference   
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

            //Bind the Gridview   
            Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
            Gridview1.DataBind();

            //After binding the gridview, we can then extract and fill the DropDownList with Data   
            DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList3");
            DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList4");
            //  FillDropDownList(ddl1);
            // FillDropDownList(ddl2);
        }
        private void AddNewRowToGrid()
        {

            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {

                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1;

                    //add new row to DataTable   
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                    //Store the current data to ViewState for future reference   

                    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;


                    for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {



                        //extract the DropDownList Selected Items   

                        DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                        DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList4");

                        // Update the DataRow with the DDL Selected Items   

                       dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column1"] = ddl1.SelectedItem.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column2"] = ddl2.SelectedItem.Text;

                        //extract the TextBox values   



                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1");
                        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox2");

                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column3"] = box1.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column4"] = box2.Text;

                    }
                    //Rebind the Grid with the current data to reflect changes   
                    Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                    Gridview1.DataBind();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("ViewState is null");

            }
            //Set Previous Data on Postbacks   
            SetPreviousData();
        }
        private void SetPreviousData()
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=medical_store_management2;Integrated Security=True");

            int rowIndex = 0;
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {

                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                        //TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                        // TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");

                        // DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                        // DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList2");

                        DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                        DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList4");
                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1");

                        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox2");

                        //Fill the DropDownList with Data   
                        //  FillDropDownList(ddl1);
                        // FillDropDownList(ddl2);

                        if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {

                            String sql = ("select price from medicine where med_name='" + ddl1.Text + "'");
                            cnn.Open();
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
                            SqlDataReader dr;
                            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                            //Set the Previous Selected Items on Each DropDownList  on Postbacks   
                            ddl1.ClearSelection();
                            ddl1.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString()).Selected = true;

                            ddl2.ClearSelection();
                            ddl2.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString()).Selected = true;

                            //Assign the value from DataTable to the TextBox   
                            if (dr.Read())
                            {
                                box1.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                            }
                            cnn.Close();
                            //box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                            box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();

                        }

                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddNewRowToGrid();
        }
        protected void Gridview1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
                if (lb != null)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
                    {
                        if (e.Row.RowIndex == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            lb.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lb.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
            int rowID = gvRow.RowIndex;
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {

                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
                {
                    if (gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        //Remove the Selected Row data and reset row number  
                        dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowID]);
                        ResetRowID(dt);
                    }
                }

                //Store the current data in ViewState for future reference  
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

                //Re bind the GridView for the updated data  
                Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }

            //Set Previous Data on Postbacks  
            SetPreviousData();
        }
        private void ResetRowID(DataTable dt)
        {
            int rowNumber = 1;
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row[0] = rowNumber;
                    rowNumber++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void InsertRecords(StringCollection sc)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
            string[] splitItems = null;
            const string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO medsale1 (mname,qty,price,total) VALUES";
            foreach (string item in sc)
            {
                if (item.Contains(","))
                {
                    splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}'); ", sqlStatement, splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2], splitItems[3]);
                }
            }

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=medical_store_management2;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), connection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            lblMessage.Text = "Records successfully saved!";
        }
        protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;
            StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //extract the TextBox values  
                        DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                        DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList4");
                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1");
                        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox2");
                        //get the values from TextBox and DropDownList  
                        //then add it to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values  
                        sc.Add(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", ddl1.SelectedItem.Text, ddl2.SelectedItem.Text, box1.Text, box2.Text));
                        //  sc.Add(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", box1.Text, box2.Text, ddl1.SelectedItem.Text, ddl2.SelectedItem.Text));
                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                    //Call the method for executing inserts  
                    InsertRecords(sc);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;
            StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //extract the TextBox values  
                        DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                        DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList4");
                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1");
                        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox2");
                        // DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                        // DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList2");

                        //get the values from TextBox and DropDownList  
                        //then add it to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values  
                        sc.Add(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", ddl1.SelectedItem.Text, ddl2.SelectedItem.Text, box1.Text, box2.Text));
                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                    //Call the method for executing inserts  
                    InsertRecords(sc);
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by detecting when user choose the `medicine name` or the `quantity`. In order to do this just add `OnSelectedIndexChanged` for your both `DropDownLists` :

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

This event will fire every time you change the selection of the item. You also need to set the `AutoPostBack` property for both `DropDownLists` to `true`, otherwise the events won't fire.

Now your code behind can look like this:

```
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList medicineName = (DropDownList)sender;
    if (medicineName.SelectedValue != "-1") // if medicine name is selected
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)medicineName.Parent.Parent; // find row 
        int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList4")).SelectedValue); // find Quantity 
        if (quantity != -1) // if quanity is selected
        {
            int price = 1; // TODO: here you take the prize from the database by medicine name
            price = price * quantity;
            TextBox txtPrice = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1"); // find price textbox for this row
            txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(price); // assign price value to this textbox
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime when user select item in `medicine name dropdownlist`, method checks if quantity is selected, and if yes you take the price from db, multiply by `quantity` and assign this value to the `textbox`. Of course in above example I didn't implement the part when you should take the price from db. Same way you have to implement the event for `quanity dropdownlist`.

Comment: this solution is not work. price from database is not display in textbox1.

Comment: Are you sure you have set the `autopostback` to `true`?

Comment: yes i set autopostback true. and it works now.. thank you